# Use Google Api Drive without a Google Drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I need to know if a file of Google Drive, which have their ID. I want to know if this file is "public".

I tried the Google APIs Drive and requires me to be logged with a Google account. The problem is that the code I am doing is for anonymous users.

Basically I want to know if the photo is published and if it does not display a warning that the photo is private.

How can I do it with PHP?.

Comment: Can't you just access it without their API (so via libcurl or fopen) and check the response?

Comment: If you go to this link: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php
It reads that require having an account

Comment: Or use your account to do all the job

Comment: I understand it is a solution, but I understand that it can not do otherwise ... hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are [required](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-auth) to be logged into a Google Account.

> All requests to the Google Drive API must be authorized by an
>   authenticated user.

However, you have at least two options:

- The first option is to use your own account to check the file. If you just need to check if it's published, you can issue the calls from your server using your account.
- The second option is to issue this `curl` command to check the return value `curl --head https://googledrive.com/host/$fileID`

  - `$fileID` is the file ID you already have. You are looking for the status response:
    `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

  If you get anything other than a `200`, the file is not available.

Comment: Ok ... many thanks ... I will try the second option. If not, I think I can only the first option. I think I'll make a tutorial API Google Drive ... there are few real examples. Thanks!

Comment: One question ... as I do to use my account details directly with PHP?. I understand it is costing a lot.

Comment: @0123 Can you rephrase that? I'm not understanding what you are saying. Are you asking if you can use your credentials to get authenticated through Google's oauth provider? In that case, yes you can.

Comment: I have a big doubt. Where do I download the PKCS 12 format file?, Is that as much as I look at the console of Google ... I do not see how. I need to const KEY_FILE. :P

Comment: Ugh ... I've already got! ... I like little things that change both administrations Google

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once 'src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId('xxxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));


$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
echo 'Googlele';


function printFile($service, $fileId) {
  try {
    $file = $service->files->get($fileId);

    print "Title: " . $file->getTitle();
    print "Description: " . $file->getDescription();
    print "MIME type: " . $file->getMimeType();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
if($service)
    {
        echo 'Connect';
         printFile($service, '0B2B9KL1Xm3swYmdkbTNqcFp4eE0');

    }
```

Response:

An error occurred: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B2B9KL1Xm3swYmdkbTNqcFp4eE0: (403) Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

But it really is impossible to have reached the limit, I will not have done any 50 tests.